# How to get the openshift node where the pod runs?

Tags: openshift

I want to get the node where the pod i'm trying to investigate run so that I can further debug the azure vm/aws ec2 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
oc get pods -o wide
```

you can get Ip of pod,Ip of node on which pod is running in last column.

[image]